# Symbol '|' in pyqtgraph

Tags: symbols, scatter-plot, pyqtgraph

I am trying to make a scatter plot with '|' symbol (as of matplotlib) in pyqtgraph. This symbol is not available in pyqtgraph. Could anyone know what should I make to reproduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no "|" symbol in pyqtgraph.
However, You can create Your own symbol from any character.
Here is a short code with function, that creates new symbol from any character:

```
import sys

import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


def custom_symbol(symbol: str, font: QFont = QtGui.QFont("San Serif")):
    """Create custom symbol with font"""
    # We just want one character here, comment out otherwise
    assert len(symbol) == 1
    pg_symbol = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    pg_symbol.addText(0, 0, font, symbol)
    # Scale symbol
    br = pg_symbol.boundingRect()
    scale = min(1. / br.width(), 1. / br.height())
    tr = QtGui.QTransform()
    tr.scale(scale, scale)
    tr.translate(-br.x() - br.width() / 2., -br.y() - br.height() / 2.)
    return tr.map(pg_symbol)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
    y = np.random.normal(size=1000)

    pg.plot(x, y, pen=None, symbol=custom_symbol("|"))

    status = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(status)
```

I've used older post to prepare this answer, that can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/g/pyqtgraph/c/zN2Q2bIgX9k?pli=1).